# Get URL of the static content folder (for backend)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, url, backend, static-content

Inside a block class which is being used to render a button in the admin panel, how to get the URL of the static content folder? Specifically, **URL of the folder with images**?

For example, in `Company_Helloworld` module an image for a custom button is located here:

> app/code/Company/Helloworld/view/adminhtml/web/images/

### Test 1

I tried this:

```
$url = $this->getViewFileUrl('Company_Helloworld::images/icon.png');
```

But it tries to retrieve the image from the `Magento/backend` theme:

> http://example.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Company_Helloworld/images/icon.png

while the image is not there, image is actually in the module's folder:

> app/code/Company/Helloworld/view/adminhtml/web/images/icon.png

### Test 2

And this:

```
$url = $this->getViewFileUrl('images/icon.png');
```

But it also tries to retrieve the image from the `Magento/backend` theme, this time without module context:

> http://example.com/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/icon.png

Is there any way to put the image in the module and not in the backend theme?

Answer (score 8):

Try to use:

```
echo $block->getViewFileUrl('Company_Helloworld::yourImage.png');
```

As a second argument of

> \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::getViewFileUrl($fileId, array $params = [])

you can set an array of next parameters:
"**module**", "**_secure**", "**theme**", "**area**" and "**locale**"

Comment: Thank you, I tired this but it gives URL of assets from the `Magento/backend` theme. I extended my question with examples.

Comment: Run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html . The location looks correct from the first sight. Also look into http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/view/static-process.html

Comment: This location is correct assuming that I put my image file inside a folder of `Magento/backend` theme. But I'd like to keep my image  in my module's folder. Is it possible?

Comment: As I understood, you want to use an image in the admin panel, am I right? "Magento/backend" is a name of default admin theme, so that's correct theme for your example, than goes locale and module name. What does confuse you? Look for uses of the method getViewFileUrl in the code, and you will find working examples for blocks and templates. Run bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and you should to find correlation between assets in the module and pub/static

Answer (score 5):

Try to use:

```
<?php
class ...

protected $_assetRepo;

public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Repository $assetRepo,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_assetRepo = $assetRepo;
    ....
}
```

Now, In you case module name is : `Company_Helloworld` and you want `icon.png` from `images` directory so

```
echo $this->_assetRepo->getUrl("Company_Helloworld::images/icon.png");
```

Hope this will help you.